# 'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'Custom Tuple'

Tags: swift, tuples

I receive this error message: `'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'KeyValuePair'` when I try to compile the app.

Here is some code sample:

```
typealias KeyValuePair = (key: String, value: String) // custom tuple

var items = [KeyValuePair]() 

func getSomeItems() -> [AnyObject]
{
    return items as [AnyObject]
}
```

If I change for example `var items = [KeyValuePair]()` to `var items = [String]()` obviously it works. I also tried force case `as!`. Doesn't work

What is wrong with this code? Is there a possibility to case some `[tuple]` to `[AnyObject]`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a mismatch ("KeyValuePair" vs "TitleValuePair") in your code. Please copy/paste the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast **class types** to `[Anyobject]` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)), but the tuple type has [compound type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html), which is not class type.

Comment: Is there any solution beside creating a custom class KeyValuePair?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only cast it to [Any], or create a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tuple use class or simply -> (key:String,value:String)

Comment: (key:String,value:String) is a tuple

Comment: meant for return type )